# Is it possible to cache music in cordova to avoid download again?

Tags: javascript, cordova, caching, audio-player

I'm working on an online music stream with JavaScript and cordova, for Android, iOS, and Windows phones.

I use HTML Audio tag, when I replay a song, it download from beginning,

My question is, is there any way to download and store it on user mobile device with cordova and play it while it downloads?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - use the FileTransfer API (part of the FileSystem plugin) to download the file. Oops, correction, it is the FileTransfer plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md).